# VBA How To Loop Through JSON response from WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

Tags: json, vba, winhttp, winhttprequest, vba6

I can't figure out how to properly loop through a JSON(Object) response from the `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest`
that I am getting.

Below are the References being used. I prefer to just keep it as is and use `WinHttpRequest`

[image]

```
Dim response As Object ' global


Function sendRequest(requestURL As String) ' send the http REST request url of API transaction
    Dim request As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    request.Open "GET", requestURL, True
    request.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenResp
    request.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    request.send
    request.waitForResponse
    
    
    Set response = ParseJson(request.ResponseText)
    

    ' Debug.Print vbNewLine & "Response : " & vbNewLine
    ' Debug.Print "Request ResponseText : " & request.ResponseText
End Function
```

Below is how the JSON response I am getting looks like. There are more records.

```
{
   "Record":[
      {
         "NameValue":[
            {
               "Name":"name1",
               "Value":"value1"
            },
            {
               "Name":"name2",
               "Value":"value2"
            }
         ]
      },
      
      {
         "NameValue":[
            {
               "Name":"name1",
               "Value":"value1"
            },
            {
               "Name":"name2",
               "Value":"value2"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The `response` is an object.
I can do `Debug.Print response("Record")(1)("NameValue")(1)("Value")` to get the first record

`Debug.Print response("Record")(1)("NameValue")(1)("Value")` ' value1

but I need to be able to loop through it to get all values and not just the first one

I can't seem to find a way to convert the JSON to an array with a array `length()` or `size()` function. I searched and found `UBound()` and `LBound()` but I think it can only be used on arrays and not Objects.

I'd appreciate any help. I do Java most of the times and things are a bit different in VBA.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a json viewer to see the structure. Looks like you want to outer For Each over response("Record") which is a collection of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

`response("record")` is a `Collection` (also anything else in `[]` in your json). Each item in that collection is a `Dictionary` (likewise anything in `{}`)

```vb
Dim itmRec, nameVal, itm

For each itmRec in response("Record")
    set nameVal = itmRec("NameValue")
    for each itm in nameVal
        debug.print itm("Name"), itm("Value")
    next itm
Next itmRec
```